# Run different npm build depending on branch

Tags: docker, github, github-actions

I have got a repo setup with 3 major branches. `master`, `development` and `demo`. When i commit I run through a global `gitops` file and pass in a `Dockerfile`.

Using Github.

If i'm pushing either `development` or `demo` i want to run `npm run development`, if `master` then i want to run `npm run production`. However I can't figure out how to pass the branch names into the docker file.

```yaml
# gitops.yaml

jobs:
  gitops:
    uses: github-actions/.github/workflows/gitops.yaml@v1
    with:
      dockerfile: ./docker/php/Dockerfile
    secrets:
      DOCKER_BUILD_ARGS: |
        ENVIRONMENT=${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/}
```

```yaml
# gitops.yaml@v1

jobs:
  build:
    - name: Build and push
      id: docker_build
      uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
      with:
        push: true
        context: .
        file: ${{ inputs.dockerfile }}
        build-args: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_BUILD_ARGS }}
```

```
# Dockerfile

FROM node:11 as node

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

RUN npm ci

COPY . .

ARG ENVIRONMENT
RUN npm run ${ENVIRONMENT} && rm -rf node_modules/
```

The above doesn't work at all, not too sure how I go about this.

Comment: What environment are you running the gitops pipelines in? Is it GItLab or some other hosting service?

Comment: Running within Github

Comment: A typical best practice is to run an identical image in all environments (don't build a special "test" image and then run a different, untested image in production).  The image's `CMD` would set the command that runs when the container starts, so something like `CMD npm run production`.

Comment: I suggest you read about environment variables in github actions. These might do what you need. I've only used github actions directly for pipelines and haven't used gitops. So I don't know how you would pass variables between the two. Otherwise, look into how gitops allows setting up variables and environments.

Answer (score 2):

you didn't specify which [event triggers your workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#delete).

assuming you are using the [`pull_request`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request) event to trigger your workflow, then you can use [`github` context](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context). specifically, `github.head_ref` (or [`GITHUB_HEAD_REF` environment variable](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables))

> The `head_ref` or source branch of the pull request in a workflow run. This property is only available when the event that triggers a workflow run is either `pull_request` or `pull_request_target`.

since you are using node, i suggest you will leverage [`NODE_ENV` environment variable](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-install) within your Dockerfile.